# How to extract sunset, sunrise from date_sun_info function

Tags: php, date

How to extract sunset, sunrise from `date_sun_info` function?

How to extract values ​for individual rows.

```
<?php
$l = date('Y-m-d');
$sun_info = date_sun_info(strtotime($l), $lat, $lon);
foreach ($sun_info as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key: " . date("H:i:s", $val) . "\n<br/>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

'date_sun_info' returns array, which means you can access its values by [] operator

```php
<?php
$l = date('Y-m-d');
$sun_info = date_sun_info(strtotime($l), $lat, $lon);
if($sun_info !== false) {
   $sunrise = $sun_info['sunrise']; //this is what you want
} else {
   die("'date_sun_info' failed");
}
```

complete list of values and doc for the function is here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-sun-info.php

Comment: I should change `$sun_info['sunrise']` into `isset($sun_info['sunrise']) ? $sun_info['sunrise'] : false` the `date_sun_info` function returns false on failure, so when it fails you will get an undefined error in your example or check if `$sun_info` is not equal to false